Delineating watersheds for thousands of polygons
I have a data layer that shows a few thousand polygons that represent areas for potential wetland restoration based on a variety of criteria (soil type, on certain types of land cover, etc).
For each of these patches, I'd like to understand certain characteristics about the land that will be contributing flow to them -- for example, I have a separate dataset of pixel-scale pollutant loading estimates, & a zonal sum over a given polygon's drainage area could help me understand how much of said pollutant it can expect to receive as inflow.
But I can't seem to identify a reasonable way to get the drainage areas for each polygon. Here's what I've tried:

A quick-&-dirty way that sacrifices a bit of accuracy to avoid a ton of processing would be to find the maximum flow accumulation cell value within each polygon. However, this is not really ideal because not all flowpaths entering the polygon can be counted on to converge to that maximum-flow-accumulation point. This becomes especially problematic when the polygon spans multiple branches of the river network, as seen here:


The maximum-flow-accumulation pixel within this polygon would account for the larger branch on the right, while entirely neglecting the one on the left.

Another approach would be to run all the polygons through the Spatial Analyst "Watershed" tool -- however, this fails to delineate accurate watersheds when a polygon is upstream of another one. See below:


In this case, because there are no other polygons upstream of it, the upper polygon's drainage area (in green) is correct. However, the lower polygon's drainage area (in pink) is not, because it should actually include the green drainage area as well.
One way to get around this would be to feed "Watershed" one polygon at a time in a loop -- but this is not workable for thousands of polygons b/c a single iteration can take as long as 15-30 min.

Running the polygons through ArcHydro's "Batch Polygon Watershed Delineation" also does not work. Referring to the case shown in the prior image, the result for a feature class containing the two patches shown would be a single polygon showing the green + the pink areas.

Finally, moving beyond ArcGIS, there seems to be a potentially ideal solution in WhiteboxTools' "Unnest Basins" tool, described here -- the tool description there perfectly articulates the same problem expressed in my #2. However, this tool seems to accept pour points and not polygons -- if I were to turn each grid cell of my 2-3K polygons into a point, I'd need to generate watersheds for something like 2 million such "pour points", which seems very inefficient / probably computationally intractable.


Is there any way to implement essentially WhiteboxTools' "Unnest Basins", but for several thousand polygons? (Preferably in ArcGIS but any platform will do if necessary!)

What shown on 2nd picture is the way to go. Convert subcatchments to polygons. Polygons to polylines, call them edges. Remove all edges that do not intersect streams. Now you have a perfect directional graph, with subcathments as nodes. Easily traceable, or even better you can run 'flow accumulation' on it.
